# C++ Client and Java Server

Tags: java, c++, client

I did a Java Socket server, and a C++ Client.
However, the client connects to the server, without problems.
But when I write something client-server, the server doesn't catch the message.
What I'm doing wrong?

A little bit of the code of the Java Server:

```
DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(usrSocket.getInputStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int data;
while((data = dis.read())>=0) {
out.write(data);
}
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
String decrypt = new String(bytes);
if(decrypt.equals("status")){
System.out.println("Status emitted.");
}
System.out.println("Received a message.");
```

C++ Client writing:

```
QByteArray qba;
qba.append(text);
sock->write(qba.data());
qDebug() << "Send status";
```

I need help with that, thank you very much.
(that variable "text" it's a QString)

---

### EDIT

Java server: That's only one part of all the code, the main thread waits for connections (Socket sock = server.accept()) and create a new thread for each user.
The code that I published of the java server, its one part of that threads for the users.
If you need ALL the code, plese tell me.

I will be waiting the answers!
Thank u very much!
Sorry if I answer ya late.

Comment: Did you use the method `accept()` on the `ServerSocket` object?

Comment: Do you need to flush the data to send it?

Comment: I think you left out too much code.

Comment: Are you using QTcpSocket by any chance?

Comment: Have you used some tool like wireshark to see which half of the system is broken -- c++ client sending data, or java server reading the data that was sent? Also, does the server get *nothing* or just not the *complete* message?

Comment: Yes, im using QTcpSocket.
The server? It gets NOTHING.

Comment: Im dwnloading wireshark right now, ill comment the results soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for **Java Server**.

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(Port_No);

Socket incomingClient = ss.accept();

InputStream i = incomingClient.getInputStream();

OutputStream o = incomingClient.getOutputStream();  // Use it write to the Client Socket

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String str = new String();

while ((str = br.readLine())!=null){


     // do what you want with the data received in str.

 }
```

Comment: First tell, me is some kind of test code...where both the codes are on the same machine or on different machine. if different, try pinging the machines first to see, that they are accessible. Then if yes. Then please see the IP address is of proper range, if its on WAN you need to have a Static Public IP. In LAN environment try any IP from Class A, B ,C

Comment: Ok, The server is on the 127.0.0.1 and the C++ Client too, the own computer works as the server and the client runs on the server.
So, im only using one computer.
When I send the message, the client dont throw any error, but the server, is not doing anything, The message is not arriving the server, the server is not listening that kind of messages, or the client is not sending the message.
Do you need the .h file and the .java file?

Comment: Dear did u implement my Server code and tested it...and Yes i hope you have added the `System.out.println(str)` inside the while loop of my code...And i am sure this will work... I have no idea about sockets in c, so frankly speaking cant detect the error in it...But i am sure abt my Server code..and yes see that you are Using the Correct Port no.... You can individually run my Server code and then try Telnetting to the server port....like 127.0.0.1:4444 so u can test it without the client to see if the server is working or not

Answer (score 0):

As youre using QTcpSocket, it highly likely that you are running the client in the default asynchronous mode. This means after when you write after calling connectToHost, nothing will be sent as the socket is *not connected*.

Try using:

```
socket->connectToHost(hostAddress, hostPort, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
if (socket->waitForConnected()) {
    QString text = "test string";
    QByteArray array;
    array.append(string);
    qDebug() << socket->write(array);
} else {
    // connect error!
}
```

Comment: I do the connectToHost, if the socket->waitForConnected() returns true, the thread that write that "status" to the server starts.
If the server could not connect or is not connected, the thread will never start...

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code reads the socket until EOS and then prints something, which by the way is not a decryption operation. Your C++ client writes something and never closes the socket. So the server can never get out of the read loop.

Comment: The variable name is decrypt because it was the first thing that came int my mind lol. And the client can't close the socket, because it needs to be sending messages, receiving messages, for that im using threads, so the server creates threads for each user, the thread just waits for client messages and do with that message whatever it needs to do. There is a main thread waiting for new connections and creating the threads for each connecion.
The server can't leave the read loop because he needs to wait for messages all the time...
I already fixed my problem.
Thanks!

Comment: @Spamdark If the client can't close the socket the server shouldn't try to read to EOS on every message.

Comment: It's a server for a game project that I am working right now :). The client connects to the server, and then start sending/receiving information, the connection should never be closed, the server should never leave the read loop, until the client close the game.
The server and the client are now working fine.
Client can close the socket, but it should not close the socket.

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly it is caused by the fact that your client is still running. Read() returns number >= 0 until the client socket is closed.